# Matrix report wrong summarized fields

Tags: reporting

[image]
Why is it calculating correctly the summarized amount for one of the fields (Invoiced revenue), but wrong for the Recognized Revenue?

Only info I could found around was this idea, but not sure if it's due to the same issue or just I'm missing something.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bq9D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I was missing a really important piece of information I missed all along since I wasn't the one who build this report.

The report was a custom report over `Contracts`(1)(stardard object) with `Subscription_Monthly_revenues__c`(N)(SMR from now on).

The fields we're summarizing displayed  here  are not from the same object. Invoiced revenue is from SMR, but the other field was from Contracts object, so the report just shows the same info for every month but because it's the value for the same contract, so It's just displaying the summary of the values of all the contracts this account had(Which in this case is 2), and therefore the final result is 5000.